# How do I write a custom `jc` parser in Python? Specifically, how do I register my custom plugin?

Tags: python, json, macos, parsing, command-line

I am trying to write a [jc](https://github.com/kellyjonbrazil/jc) virtualbox plugin to display VM info (command is `vboxmanage showvminfo  myserver`).

To do so, I've copied `jc/parsers/foo.py` to

`/Users/myuser/Library/Application Support/jc/parsers/vboxmanageinfo.py`

I've done nothing much to that file yet, figured I'd just try and use pdb to step through data coming into its `parse` function.

But when I try to execute

`vboxmanage showvminfo  myserver  | jc --vboxmanageinfo` I get

```
vboxmanage showvminfo  myserver  | jc --vboxmanageinfo
jc:  Error - Missing or incorrect arguments. Use "jc -h" for help.
```

Now, if I do `jc -h` I get a list of parsers:

```
Parsers:
        --acpi           `acpi` command parser
        --airport        `airport -I` command parser
        --airport-s      `airport -s` command parser
        --arp            `arp` command parser
        ...
        --uptime         `uptime` command parser
        --vmstat         `vmstat` command parser
        --vmstat-s       `vmstat` command streaming parser
        --w              `w` command parser
```

which is missing `--vboxmanageinfo`.

OK, let's go to `jc/lib.py` where the parser list ultimately seems to come from a hardcoded list.

```
__version__ = '1.18.7'

parsers = [
    'acpi',
    'airport',
    'airport-s',
    ...
```

which as far as I can tell is the only thing being fed to the usage/help function.

Is there some registration step to make `jc` aware of my plugin parser that I am missing?

I followed the instructions at [jc's doc for custom parsers](https://github.com/kellyjonbrazil/jc#custom-parsers)

Answer (score 2):

OK, feeling quite silly by now, but so be it.  The next person can learn from my mistake.

The problem is that I first dropped my new parser into `site-packages/jc/parsers`.  Then looking at the doc some more I moved it to

`<appdata>/jc/parsers` i.e. the same named directory under a different parent.

but the actual name expected from `jc` is

```
Custom local parser plugins may be placed in a jc/jcparsers folder in your local "App data directory":

Linux/unix: $HOME/.local/share/jc/jcparsers
macOS: $HOME/Library/Application Support/jc/jcparsers
Windows: $LOCALAPPDATA\jc\jc\jcparsers
```

So, no, not `.../parsers`, but `.../jcparsers`.  Now it works, but it remains entirely silent until you read the doc correctly.

My plugin now appears after the delivered ones in help:

```
        --zipinfo        `zipinfo` command parser
        --vboxmanageinfo Provides parser metadata (version, author, etc.)
```